# Powershell: Logging foreach changes

Tags: powershell

I have put together a script inspired from a number of sources. The purpose of the powershell script is to scan a directory for files (.SQL), copy all of it to a new directory (retain the original), and scan each file against a list file (CSV format - containing 2 columns: OldValue,NewValue), and replace any strings that matches. What works: moving, modifying, log creation.

What doesn't work:
Recording in the .log for the changes made by the script.

Sample usage: .\ConvertSQL.ps1 -List .\EVar.csv -Files \SQLFiles\Rel_1

```
Param (
    [String]$List = "*.csv",
    [String]$Files = "*.sql"
)

function Get-TimeStamp {
    return "[{0:dd/MM/yyyy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
}

$CustomFiles = "$Files\CUSTOMISED"

IF (-Not (Test-Path $CustomFiles))
{
    MD -Path $CustomFiles
}
Copy-Item "$Files\*.sql" -Recurse -Destination "$CustomFiles"

$ReplacementList = Import-Csv $List;

Get-ChildItem $CustomFiles |

ForEach-Object {
    $LogFile = "$CustomFiles\$_.$(Get-Date -Format dd_MM_yyyy).log"
    Write-Output "$_ has been modified on $(Get-TimeStamp)." | Out-File "$LogFile"
    
    $Content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName;
    foreach ($ReplacementItem in $ReplacementList)
    {
        $Content = $Content.Replace($ReplacementItem.OldValue, $ReplacementItem.NewValue)

    }
    Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Value $Content
}
```

Thank you very much.

Edit: I've cleaned up a bit and removed my test logging files.

Here's the snippet of code that I've been testing with little success. I put the following right under $Content= Content.Replace($ReplacementItem.OldValue, $ReplacementItem.NewValue)

```
 if ( $_.FullName -like '*TEST*' ) {
    "This is a test." | Add-Content $LogFile
}
```

I've also tried to pipe out the Set-Content using Out-File. The outputs I end up with are either a full copy of the contents of my CSV file or the SQL file itself. I'll continue reading up on different methods. I simply want to, out of hundreds to a thousand or so lines, to be able to identify what variables in the SQL has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of piping output to Add-Content, pipe the log output to: Out-File -Append

Edit: compare the content using the Compare-Object cmdlet and evaluate it's ouput to identify where the content in each string object differs.

Comment: Thanks. This does not output any information to the $LogFile. Changes however are made accordingly to the SQL files.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I modified my response.

Comment: Thanks Robo! This might do the trick actually. Will update of outcome: will compare the original and custom script and output the differences.